# Spring WebClient not processing JSON content

Tags: json, spring, webclient

I have an app that uses WebClient to fetch JSON data from ComicVine as follows:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
  .baseUrl(url)
  .defaultHeaders(
    headers -> {
      headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
      headers.add(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "ComiXed/0.7");
    })
  .build();

Mono<ComicVineIssuesQueryResponse> request =
  client
    .get()
    .uri(url)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(ComicVineIssuesQueryResponse.class);

ComicVineIssuesQueryResponse response = request.block();
```

For a time this worked. But then, all of a sudden, it's throwing the following root exception when it executes:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/json' not supported for bodyType=org.comixed.scrapers.comicvine.model.ComicVineIssuesQueryResponse
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$readWithMessageReaders$12(BodyExtractors.java:201)
```

I'm not sure why it all of a sudden won't process JSON data. My unit test, which is explicitly returning JSON data and setting the content type properly:

```
private MockWebServer comicVineServer;

this.comicVineServer.enqueue(
  new MockResponse()
    .setBody(TEST_GOOD_BODY)
    .addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
```

Any ideas why this is the case? It's happening across multiple classes that use this same setup for WebClient and for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some digging, I added the following code to get the JSON as a String and then use ObjectMapper to convert it to the target type:

```
Mono<String> request =
  client
    .get()
    .uri(url)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(String.class);

String value = request.block();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ComicVineIssuesQueryResponse response = mapper.readValue(value, ComicVineIssuesQueryResponse.class);
```

This quickly exposed the underlying problem, which was that two instance variables in the response were annotated with the same JSON field name. Once I fixed that, things started working correctly again.

Answer (score -1):

you can parse the json content to string without calling block method.

option 1) [Jackson2Tokenizer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/codec/json/Jackson2Tokenizer.java)

option 2) put your code which is calling "objectMapper.readValue(..) .." **inside map operator**.

Comment: You can't parse the content when the underlying call is throwing an exception, which was the problem. I posted my own answer above after I found the root cause.